# mock self.variable for my unit test in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, unit-testing, mocking

I have a scenario where I want to mock a variable which initialized in my **init** method a class :

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo
    
    def method1(self):
        df = self.foo.some_method(var1='var1')
        ** more code **
```

some_method is a method in another class of which foo is an object

```
class SecondClass():
      def __init__(self, var1):
          self.var1 = var1
      
      def some_method(self):
          return df
```

Now i have to write a unit test for method1 and i want to mock `self.foo.some_method` so that i can return the desired df for my unit test. How do i do that?

Comment: Why not create MyClass with a test double of the collaborator, so you control it? Then you don't need to interfere with the thing you're actually testing. The fact that it's passed in as an argument to `__init__` makes that really easy.

Comment: I am not sure, what you mean by test double. Can you explain it?

Comment: Generic term for mocks etc., see e.g. https://engineering.pivotal.io/post/the-test-double-rule-of-thumb/

Comment: I understood the concept of test double but can you show me how to do it? Because if I do create a fake class, how would I assign it to my self.foo variable, I believe setattr won't work here

Comment: How do you think? You pass it in (via `__init__`) when you create the MyClass instance to test.